# Constant application settings for Windows From application

Tags: winforms, settings

What is the method to save user preferences in windows application? I used Settings section in Solution properties that cooperate with `Properties.Settings.Default.SomeProperty`. During the application live properties are fine. However if i reopen application settings are reset to the default state.
And i can't find any conf files where settings are reside. So i am wondering if i am wrong with useing this kind of `Settings` to save user preferences ? Maybe it is better to add app.conf file and save settins in app setting section? Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting your Properties.Settings.Default.Some Property you must call Properties.Settings.Default.Save(). Otherwise it will not be written to disk.

Comment: Many thanks!!! And what and where is the file used by the `Properties`?

Comment: My pleasure.  It saves to App.config in your solution folder.  You should find the value under <userSettings><yourApp.Properties.Settings><setting>